# Can I use Jenkins and Nexus without Maven

Tags: jenkins, nexus

I am in a process of configuring Jenkins to deploy artifacts. I only need apache ant and java to create artifacts(both are available on the host machine) and no other external libraries. So, I think using Maven will make it unnecessarily complex as I have only 2 ant files. I want to keep it as simple as possible.

What I want to achieve is:
1. Trigger a Jenkins job 'A' to build the artifact and deploy it to nexus repository.
2. Trigger another Jenkins Job 'B' to take same artifact generated in in step above and deploy it to target environment.

Can anyone please help me to identify challenges with my approach and share some useful links to achieve what I have specified.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer is **Yes** you can. Each of the component you mentioned can be used individually and can be integrated into your build pipeline. TBH, your use case isn't one off and can be easily done if you start [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/).

Comment: Thanks, I used jenkins plugin for uploading artifact to Nexus. Now, build part is much simple and clean. Started with deployment part.

Comment: @user1634358, I did you managed to get back the artefact from Nexus in your job "B" without maven? I mean in a jenkins pipeline.. thx